# General Error 1215: Cannot Add Foreign Key Constraint for Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Below are the two migrations I tried to run in the order stated. The varitypes are the same, and I'm adding the FK after making the table, but it's still throwing me the `1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint` error.

> General Error 1215: Cannot Add Foreign Key Constraint for Laravel 5

`2019_12_10_130856_all_skillset.php`

```php
public function up(){
    Schema::create('all_skillsets', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->char('skillset');
    });
}
```

`2019_12_10_300000_skillset.php`

```php
public function up(){
    Schema::create('skillsets', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('spid');
        $table->char('skill');
    });

    Schema::table('skillsets', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->foreign('skill')->references('skillset')->on('all_skillsets');
        $table->foreign('spid')->references('id')->on('players');
    });
}
```

Comment: The foreign key statement will fail if the table being referred to does not exist yet.

Comment: @MikeFoxtech The migrations are in order, so there is already an `all_skillsets` table prior to referencing it as a foreign key

Comment: @Dragonsnap please post `players` migration too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error must be for this line:

`$table->foreign('skill')->references('skillset')->on('all_skillsets');`

You should refer to the primary key **all_skillsets** table.
Don't forget the foreign key type must be equal to the owner's key type.

E.g. If you define the owner's key with `increment`, you must define the foreign key with `unsignedInteger`.